# VHDL Program counter using signals and previously made components?

Tags: cpu, vhdl, mux, program-counter

I am currently in the middle of a project where I am attempting to design a single cycle cpu. I am doing this without any pipe-lining, since that would greatly add to the complexity of the design. I am simply taking baby steps as I learn this. I find myself stuck at this portion where I am simply attempting to code a Program Counter(PC) using previously made components.

The model of my design looks like this [picture here](http://imgur.com/qaSp6y5). Sorry, no idea why it came out dark, but if you click on it it shows correctly. The PC and theMUX are both 32 bit components, so I assume the adder is as well.

Here is the code I have been given, my implementation begins at the begin statement on line 41.
Pay no attention to it for now, its just a bunch of random gibberish I was attempting.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
---------------------------------------------------
entity pc_update is
    port( clk: in std_logic; -- clock
        incH_ldL: in std_logic; -- increment PC = PC + 4 when high,
                                -- load PCInput when low
    PCInput: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- external input for PC
    InstrAddr: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ); -- instruction address
end entity pc_update;
----------------------------------------------------
architecture pc_update_arch of pc_update is
    component register32 is
        port( clr: in std_logic; -- async. clear
              clk: in std_logic; -- clock
               ld: in std_logic; -- load  
                D: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- data input
                Q: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ); -- data output
    end component register32;

    component mux2to1_32 is
        port( sel: in std_logic; -- selection bit input
               X0: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- first input
                X1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- second input
                 Y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)); -- output
    end component mux2to1_32;

    signal PC_current: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- the current state of PC reg        
    signal PC_add_4: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- output from the adder 
    signal PC_next: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- output from the MUX

    begin

    PC: register32 Port Map(
        clk, Q, clr, D);    
    MUX: mux2to1_32 Port Map(
        X0,sel,X1,Y);

    process (incH_ldL)
        begin
        wait until (clk = '1');
        if  incH_1dL = '0' then
            InstrAddr <= X0;
        else InstrAddr <= X1;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture pc_update_arch;
```

I am fairly new to this so I have only a faint idea of how signals work, and no idea how I am supposed to implement the components into the design. I am also confused that I wasnt asked to build the adder ahead of time. Is it now necessary to use it as a component im guessing?

Anyhow, I have attempted different things that stumbled upon searching, such as the port mapping you see. But I always get some sort of error, currently the error im receiving is that objects Q, clr, and D are used but not declared. How do I declare them?
If I get rid of those statements, the error simply repeats for objects X0, X1, and Y.
Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Also, just in case you need them,
The register

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

---------------------------------------------------

entity register32 is port( 
clr: in std_logic; -- async. clear
clk: in std_logic; -- clock
ld: in std_logic; -- load
D: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- data input
Q: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ); -- data output
end entity register32;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture register32_arch of register32 is

begin 
    process(clk, clr)
    begin
        if clr = '1' then
            q <= x"00000000";
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
           if ld = '1' then
               q <= d;
           end if;
        end if;
    end process;
END register32_arch;
```

and the MUX

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

---------------------------------------------------

entity mux2to1_32 is
port( sel: in std_logic; -- selection bit input
X0: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- first input
X1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- second input
Y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)); -- output

end entity mux2to1_32;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture mux2to1_32_arch of mux2to1_32 is
begin

    Y <= X1 when (SEL = '1') else X0;

end architecture mux2to1_32_arch;
```

**EDIT**
Ok, NO idea if I did this correctly, but I rewrote the portmaps. I was having errors of port names (sel, clk, X0, X1..etc) being "used but not initialized. So that is why clr, clk and ld have initial values. Once again, no idea if that is correct, but it made the errors go away. I also realized I never added the register32 and mux2to1_32 VHDL files to my project, and after doing so got rid of the other errors I was having.

So as stands, the code compiles, I have included in the project a VWF simulation file for testing, but I KNOW the results are gonna be incorrect.

I dont know everything that is wrong yet, but I know I need to do something with PC_add_4. THis value needs to basically be (PC_current + 4), but Im not sure how to do this.

Here is the updated portion of code(everything else is the same)

```
PC: register32 Port Map(
    clr => '0', 
    clk => '0',
     ld => '1',  
      Q => PC_current, 
      D => PC_next 
      );

MUX: mux2to1_32 Port Map(
    sel => incH_ldL, 
    X0 => PCInput ,
    X1 => PC_add_4,
    Y =>  PC_next 
    );

process (incH_ldL)
    begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if  incH_ldL = '0' then
            InstrAddr <= PC_current;
        else InstrAddr <= PC_add_4;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

And, in case they help, my list of errors..im guessing the pin related errors are because I dont have any hardware assignments made yet.

1. Warning (10541): VHDL Signal Declaration warning at pc_update.vhd(38): used implicit default value for signal "PC_add_4" because signal was never assigned a value or an explicit default value. Use of implicit default value may introduce unintended design optimizations.
2. Warning (10492): VHDL Process Statement warning at pc_update.vhd(61): signal "clk" is read inside the Process Statement but isn't in the Process Statement's sensitivity list
3. Warning: Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND
4. Warning: Design contains 34 input pin(s) that do not drive logic
5. Warning: Found 32 output pins without output pin load capacitance assignment
6. Warning: The Reserve All Unused Pins setting has not been specified, and will default to 'As output driving ground'.
7. Warning: Can't generate programming files because you are currently using the Quartus II software in Evaluation Mode
8. Warning: No paths found for timing analysis
9. Critical Warning: No exact pin location assignment(s) for 66 pins of 66 total pins

**SECOND EDIT**
So yeah I fixed up my code by adding
    PC_add_4 <= (PC_current + 4 );
after the port mappings, and adding "clk" to the process sensitivity list.
However my waveforms in my simulation are still wrong I believe, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKnfO.jpg).

It appears to be treating incH_lDL as a clear signal, rather than simply passing PCInput to InstrAddr. This is most likely due to my setting of it to a default '0' in the port map. I did this earlier because it was giving me "used but not declared" errors. Ill try messing with it and post my findings.

**Third EDIT**

I have edited my code as such:

```
process (incH_ldL, clk)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if  (incH_ldL = '0') then
            InstrAddr <= PCInput ;
        else InstrAddr <= PC_add_4;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

My simulation now shows that when incH_lDL = 0, PCInput is loaded into InstrAddr, however, when incH_lDL = 1, it simply loads the value '4', and doesnt increment at the start of every clock cycle like its supposed to...I need to make use of PC_current, but I am not sure how....sicne you cant assign one signal to another like "PC_current <= PCInput". I will try some more things,in the mean time, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**FOURTH EDIT**
THanks to anyone still reading this, and bearing through all the reading.

I have attempted to use PC_next and PC_current in my implementation, but have run into "multiple constant drivers for net "PC_next" errors.

MY process code:

```
process (incH_ldL, clk, PC_next, PC_current)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if  (incH_ldL = '0') then
            PC_next <= PCInput;
        else PC_next  <= PC_add_4;
        end if;
    end if; 
    InstrAddr <= PC_current;    
end process;
```

I am aware that this error comes when these assignments are made within loops? I am truly at a loss here at what to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port maps in the first code need to be ported to signals. You are placing the port names of the components in the port map, which is incorrect. What you would like to do is create signals that can connect those components, and place them in the port map fields instead (to match the connections in your image).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I am still new to this site and its mechanics, I have no idea if youll notice if I dont comment, but I added details and some new code.

Comment: Ok so you're trying to simulate your design using the waveforms, that's good. The warnings are pin related meaning when you try to emulate your design on one of the development boards/FPGAs. So don't worry about those for simulating. When you want to emulate you'll have to decide where you want to map your inputs and outputs. To start on that, depending on your dev board altera will have .csv file you can import to your project and help you out.

Comment: Alright, so my only concern should be with the first two warnings then? Great. Ill get working on finding any solution before posting again.

Comment: Alright I returned! Thank you so much for your help. I ended up simply adding "PC_add_4 <= (PC_current + 4);" after the port maps, and included clk to my sensitivity list. After that, no errors or worrisome warnings. 

BUUUUT as expected my simulation is off. Ill post details in my post.

Comment: Your constant driver error comes from multiple components or different processes within a component trying to write to the same signal. In this case your PC and mux are writing to the same signal which is incorrect. Try fixing that to eliminate the error using 2 different signals and connect them accordingly.

Comment: What I was trying to do with that is somehow connect the output 'Y' of the MUX to input 'D' of the PC register. SO technically Y and D should be the same value, with the PC_Next signal carrying the value. I understand why writing it that way would cause issues, I definitely thought about it when I wrote it, but Im not sure what to do otherwise.

Comment: I was using [this](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/usage-of-components-and-port-mapping.html) page as a reference for connecting components. In that example, both "sum" and "a" write to "c1". This works im guessing because they values are not used in a loop like in my code. How do I get around this without writing another signal?

Comment: Can't make out your code anymore there's too many edits and issues here. If you can, finish this post (answered) and start a new post with your new problem (post the whole code) and we'll take it from there again